# How to get or assign a color category to a mailitem?

Tags: vba, colors, outlook, categories

```
Dim oSel As Outlook.Selection

    Set oSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

Dim oEmail As Outlook.mailitem

    Set oEmail = oSel.Item(1)
```

I am on a network-share and would like to

1) get the color, i.e. grey (olCategoryColorGray=13) assigned to the currently selected mail item (oEmail is categorized to color grey) and,

2) assign a different color category to it, say red (olCategoryColorRed=1).

Your kind help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/macro-add-remove-category/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.categories.aspx) property of the MailItem class to get the list of assigned categories to the item. Categories is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item.

Use the [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/category-color-property-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm2427)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) property of the Category class to get an `OlCategoryColor` constant that indicates the color used by the Category object. You can share the same color for multiple categories, by specifying the same constant that represents the category color in the `OlCategoryColor` enumeration for those Category objects.

```
 private void EnumerateCategories()
 {
    Outlook.Categories categories = Application.Session.Categories;
    foreach (Outlook.Category category in categories)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine(category.Name);
       Debug.WriteLine(category.CategoryID);
       Debug.WriteLine(category.Color);
    }
 }

 private void AddACategory()
 {
    Outlook.Categories categories = Application.Session.Categories;
    if (!CategoryExists("ISV"))
    {
        Outlook.Category category = categories.Add("ISV",
        Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorDarkBlue,
        Outlook.OlCategoryShortcutKey.olCategoryShortcutKeyCtrlF11);
    }
 }

 private bool CategoryExists(string categoryName)
 {
    try
    {
       Outlook.Category category = Application.Session.Categories[categoryName];
       if(category != null)
       {
          return true;
       }
       else
       {
          return false;
       }
    }
    catch { return false; }
 }
```